# VueJS - bind an object of attributes

Tags: html, vue.js, binding, attributes

in `Vue js` let's suppose we have this code:

```
<script setup>
import { Link } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import { reactive } from 'vue'
</script>

<template>
        <div data-bs-toggle="collapse"
             data-bs-target="#Dashboard"
             aria-expanded="false"
             aria-controls="Dashboard"
        >       
           <i class="fa-solid fa-chart-line fa-lg lh-1"></i> 
        </div>
</template>
```

let's suppose we have tons of `divs` like this one and with the same attributes, then instead of typing same attributes again and again, can't we just extract attributes to an object and then binding them, like this:

```
<script setup>
import { Link } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import { reactive } from 'vue'

const Object = reactive({
  data-bs-toggle:"collapse"
  data-bs-target:"#Dashboard"
  aria-expanded=:false
  aria-controls=:"Dashboard"
});
</script>
<template>
        <div :attr="Object" >       
           <i class="fa-solid fa-chart-line fa-lg lh-1"></i> 
        </div>
</template>
```

can we do something like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `v-bind`:
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#binding-multiple-properties-using-an-object

```
<div v-bind="Object" >
```